# Homology of orientable 4-manifold given fundamental group and Euler characteristic

Tags: homology-cohomology, cw-complexes, 4-manifolds

I'm working through old topology quals and came across this question:

Let M be a closed, connected, orientable 4-manifold with fundamental group $π_1(M) = \mathbb{Z}_3 ∗ \mathbb{Z}_3$ and Euler characteristic $χ(M) = 5$.

(a) Compute $H_i(M,\mathbb{Z})$ for all $i$.

(b) Prove that M is not homotopy equivalent to any CW complex with no 3-cells.

I know $H_0 = H_4 = \mathbb{Z}$, and $H_1$ is the abelianization of $π_1(M)$. I'm lost on finding $H_2$ and $H_3$. I assume we need to use $\chi(M) = \sum_n (-1)^n \text{ rank}(H_n)$ at some point.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: The most efficient tool for figuring out $H_3$ is Poincare Duality: $H_3$ is isomorphic to $H^1$. You can figure out $H^1$ from the Universal Coefficient Theorem and knowledge of $H_1$. Then for $H_2$ you can use what you wrote about the Euler characteristic.

Comment: For (b), you might try examining what the cellular chain complex might look like if $M$ had a CW structure with no $3$-cells, and attempt to find a contradiction with the homology groups you computed.